# Use activity as a dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I want to use an activity as a dialog in my android application. Till now, I've used `AlertDialogs` but I want to make my app more fancy. I've done a lot of research on this but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

I created a new activity named `DialogActivity.java` and `dialogactivty` for the java and xml files respectively.

So, How do I call this activity as a dialog in some other activity?

AND

How do I give this activity a round cornered rectangle dialog shape?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: set a dialog theme to the activity

Comment: @Raghunandan Could you please give me a sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a dialog theme to activity as

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

and use

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" /> // api level 11 and above
```

in manifest for the activity required.

You need to start the activity using `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: @ChinmayDabke http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html),

> If you want a custom dialog, you can instead display an Activity as a
>   dialog instead of using the Dialog APIs. Simply create an activity and
>   set its theme to `Theme.Holo.Dialog` in the  manifest element:
>
> ```
> <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
> ```
>
> That's it. The activity now displays in a dialog window instead of
>   fullscreen.

Use `Theme.Dialog` for API 10 or lower.

Comment: @antimoWhat should I do if my app supports both API 10 lower and higher?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

entry in manifest for the activity you required.

Answer (score -1):

@ChinmayDabke To display with rounded corners, you need to create a new `shape` using xml and set it as the background drawable.. be sure to also set transparency for your activity. For more detailed information on this, there are many up-to-date topics available - I just wanted to give a quick answer to this old post, since you had asked!

---

My mistake - you don't need to set as Transparent - I meant to say set no *Titlebar!*

Example:

Create a Shape for the rounded background, inside your *res/drawable* folder:

**shape_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorOfActivityHere"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="12dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Then set the shape as the Background of your activity's parent layout:

**layout_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your Activity.java, set no titlebar:

**Activity.java**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```